# Flutter: Lost connection to device (production app)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

In both debug mode and the app uploaded to play store, when I open the app for the very first time, it crashes. Though if I open it again, everything works fine then.

```
I/zygote64(11974): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService>: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.ved.mentor101app-AbvtNHTF_HGKeS2lffOLiw==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
Lost connection to device.

D/AndroidRuntime(11974): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(11974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11974): Process: com.ved.mentor101app, PID: 11974
E/AndroidRuntime(11974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ved.mentor101app-AbvtNHTF_HGKeS2lffOLiw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ved.mentor101app-AbvtNHTF_HGKeS2lffOLiw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.ved.mentor101app-AbvtNHTF_HGKeS2lffOLiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

E/AndroidRuntime(11974):    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.ved.mentor101app-AbvtNHTF_HGKeS2lffOLiw==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime(11974):        ... 13 more
I/zygote64(11974): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=44KB
I/zygote64(11974): After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=44KB
I/zygote64(11974): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/Process (11974): Sending signal. PID: 11974 SIG: 9er
```

Complete debug statement(can't upload in the text since StackOverflow doesn't allow its length):
[image: 1/3][image: 2/3][image: 3/3]

```
// flutter doctor -v:
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.2-pre.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.2.2-pre.1 at C:\Users\Dell\flutter
    • Framework revision 03b53e0901 (7 weeks ago), 2019-04-20 19:15:26 +0530
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • RMX1801 • 8843cc23 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcIaC.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzpLH.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnqNV.png
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you are using a very outdated version of Flutter you should update it. At this time the current version on the stable channel is v1.5.4-hotfix.2 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases . What package are you using that requires firebase?

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I have made some custom changes in the flutter source code for my app, the upgrade will probably remove them, I will upgrade flutter soon tho, On your question, I have 6-7 packages but firebase_analytics was the last one added to the project before this error break out!

Comment: Can you check your gradle. Sounds like you might be experiencing references/dependencies issues https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23545#issuecomment-434041145 https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/754

Answer (score 7):

What finally helped  was:

in app level `build.gradle`

```
 defaultConfig {      
    
    minSdkVersion 23
    
}
```

in project level `gradle.properties` add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

in `build.gradle` add

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

> Your gradle version should be greater than 5

you can skip that Kotlin plugin if you are not using Kotlin support
Dont forget to run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub upgrade`

These changes helped me preventing my app crashes, It should help you too.

Comment: Thanks, adding the lines to gradle.properties fixed the issue for me. Any idea why it behaves like that?

Comment: with sdk updates,some codes get decayed and the community has to change the configuration files.But we use our project locally that was built on earlier versions, So some code conflicts arises,and these types of behaviour is noticed. If we create a new project from scratch and then we implement the function then it is less error prone.

Comment: I am using the same config values, still the app is crashing on simulator but not on a real device.